Universe Sandbox and Hillsphere calculation (Updated)
So according to this calculation here including:

A Gas Giant of 12 Jupiter Masses
A Sun like Star of 1047.57 Jupiter Masses
and a semi major axis of the Planet of 1 AU


The Gas Giant should have a hill sphere of 0.15627750286244 Astronomical Units. But that seems very large. And if i place a body in 0.1 AU Distance of the Planet, it will quickly leave its orbit.
What am i missing here?


The Gas Giant should have a hill sphere of 0.15627750286244 Astronomical Units. But that seems very large.

Your planet is 12 Jupiter masses in size... it is very large! It probably counts as a small brown dwarf... GU Piscium has a similar mass, for example. Your "planet" masses about as much as the whole of the solar system excluding the Sun.
Anyway, I get the same Hill radius that you did, so your calculation is probably correct.

And if i place a body in 0.1 AU Distance of the Planet, it will quickly leave its orbit.

The wikipedia article on the subject says "Detailed numerical calculations show that orbits at or just within the Hill sphere are not stable in the long term; it appears that stable satellite orbits exist only inside 1/2 to 1/3 of the Hill radius".
Try placing the body at .5 AU instead.

Good advice.  I was thinking that a distance of 0.666 of the Hill Sphere was too far from the planet.
